# Пример MVC + сервера

Tags: javascript, mvc, архитектура, node.js

Для тех, кто не знает предыстории, то я скажу, что её лучше и не знать, а все начать с начала.
 Я только учусь, и мне не легко даются вписывания сервера в mvc. Я прошу помочь мне вправить мозги на простом примере.

Из прошлой дискуссии я выяснил, что бизнес-логика приложения находится в модели, а задача контроллера - это:

```
дата = модель.выполнитьТакоеТоДействие();
вью.сделатьЭто( дата );
```

И теперь к реалии... У меня по нажатии на кнопку nodejs запускает поток данных, которые мне нужно обработать. Nodejs модуль я воспринил как сервер, который шлет данные по требованию.
И вот, забыв на мгновение многие годы работы с mvc вне вэба, я смог переключиться на доселе незнакомую мне реализацию, и у меня все стало ломаться. Объясню, почему: данные с сервера - это данные, влеяющие на логику приложения. Мне нужно принять эти данные, распарсить, поместить данные, построенные на основе обработанной информации, в коллекцию и послать событие о том, что модель подготовила данные и их можно забрать.
И тут в дело вступает контроллер. Поймав событие, он забирает данные из модели и передает их во вью, чтобы та их напечатала и вывела на экран.

Пока я остановлюсь и спрошу: это правильно?

***Дополнение:***

```
Ну почти, если мне не изменяет память о строении MVC и я правильно вас понял, вы выкинули куда-то представления.
```

В самом конце упомянул:

```
забирает данные из модели и передает их во вью, чтобы та их напечатала и вывела на экран.
```

И раз у меня вроде пока все получается, то я продолжу...

У, предположим, хотя оно так и есть, nodejs модуль считается законченным и мне не подвласным, максимум, что я могу, это зарядить в него ссылку на callback, в который будет поступать информация. И, по сути, это выглядит, как если бы в жизни у меня был сервер со стримом данных. И единственное, что мне приходит в голову, это передать при инициализации приложения ссылку в nodejs на метод, находящийся в модели, при её создании. Это будет правильно? То есть получается, что в модель получает поток данных с сервера самостоятельно и обрабатывает их так, как ей это угодно. Это правильно?

Comment: @Alex Krass, Спасибо Вам! Я немного дополнил вопрос и жду от Вас ответа:)

Comment: Я вот ещё раз перечитал и мне показалось, что ответ Вы уже дали, когда написали, что контроллер получает данные и передает в модель. В моем случаи данные о файловой системе тоже контроллер должен принимать? Потом передовать их в модель, а возвращенные данные передавать во вью?

Comment: Перевел комментарии в ответ.

Comment: Тогда соберите все комменты в ответ и уже потом я спрошу ещё:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну почти, если мне не изменяет память о строении MVC и я правильно вас понял, вы выкинули куда-то представления. Если быть точнее:

1. Контроллер получает данные от пользователя.
2. Контроллер данные передает в выбранную им модель, которая анализирует их и выдает нужную информацию (в т.ч. соединяясь с БД) обратно в контроллер.
3. Контроллер выбирает нужное представление, которое подготавливает для отображения информацию, полученную от модели.
4. Результат работы представления отдается пользователю для визуализации.

[image]

**-- UPD --**

Если я вас правильно понял, то вы хотите, чтобы ваша собственная модель опрашивала закрытый модуль nodejs и разбирала полученные от него данные? Если так, то да, это будет правильно. Так как архитектура MVC позволяет делать дополнительные прослойки между шагами, если они не противоречат общей картине. Получится модель, которая обращается к другой модели.

> В моем случаи данные о файловой системе тоже контроллер должен принимать?

Да, контроллер выступает как посредник в передаче данных. Он их принимает и отправляет дальше на обработку тому, кто их должен получить согласно своей логике. При этом он также может передавать данные от одной модели к другой и т.д. Он данные не обрабатывает, а просто перенаправляет.

Comment: Не опрашивать, а принимать данные. Nodejs посылает данные, и мне нужно их принять. При инстале у меня есть ссылка на метод nodejs, в параметры которого нужно передать ссылку на метод, который будет принимать данные. И вот я хочу при инстале создать модель и её метод передать в качестве того самого callback.
И если рассматривать модуль nodejs как сервер, а сервер как модель, то получится, что модель на клиенте передала ссылку на себя в модель на сервере и получает от неё данные напрямую. Так можно?

Comment: @vas, в принципе да, так можно. Хотя тут уже надо подумать, исходя из полной картины проекта. Может быть, стоит добавить прослойку-контроллер для разделения порядка обработки данных, а может, он тут вообще и не нужен. У вас же активная модель, насколько я понял по предыстории? Тогда можно и из модели оповестить подписанные представления.

Comment: Или же вообще рассматривать nodejs модуль как пользователя, который постоянно шлет вам данные в контроллер. Но это я уже довольно далеко забежал, но как вариант может быть и такое. В общем тут больше от конкретики зависит.